# VBA code to sum total of like account numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that matches 2 columns A VS C for like account numbers. If numbers match than it finds if the amounts in Column B & D match. If it does it pastes the lines of data to another spreadsheet. 
I am coding a statement to find the like account numbers in column A VS C, but if the amounts don't match in column B & D than it needs to find the like account numbers in column A and sum there amounts to see if it matches the amount in column B.
How would I write the code to collect the sum of the same account numbers in column A?

```
If Acct = MatchAcct Then 
   If Amount <> MatchAmount Then
      If Acct = nonmatchacct Then
          (sum the values in column B for the matched account #s in column A)
```

The code above says if the Acct (Column A account #'s) = MatchAcct (Column C account #'s) then if Amount (Column B value) doesn't equal MatchAmount (Column D value) then the code sees if Acct (Column A account #'s) equals nonmatchacct (any other account # in Column A). If the account # matches then I want it to sum those amounts in column B.

Comment: why not use `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS`?

Comment: can you add example?

Comment: Google, F1, it's a native excel function